# Using try and catch blocks to get user input for finding an average of N integers

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch

I'm very new to Java and I'm trying to write a program that takes asks for `N integers` in an `array`. And I need a try and `catch block` to make sure it is a positive number. Then I need the user to input the numbers for the `array` and find the average of the numbers.

```
public class Exceptions {

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Enter how many integers in the array
    System.out.println("Find the average of how many integers?");

    int integers = scanner.nextInt();
    int positive[] = null; // array
    int integersInTheArray = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    try {
        positive = new int[integers];
        if (integers < 1)
            throw new ArithmeticException("Must be an integer of one or more.");

    } // End try

    catch (ArithmeticException eghx) {
        System.out.println(eghx.getMessage());
    } // End catch

    for (int i = 0; i < positive.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Which integers to find the average of?" + " " + "#" + (i + 1));
        integersInTheArray = scanner.nextInt();
        sum += integersInTheArray;
    }

    System.out.println("The average is: " + (sum / integers));

}// End main
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line "int integers = scanner.nextInt();" will throw an exception if the entered string by the user is not an integer. Hence, a try/catch block for InputMismatchException is needed already here.

```
int integers;
try{
    integers = scanner.nextInt();
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.err.out("No integer! Do something :(");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you can do it using the loop

```
boolean flag = false;
while(!flag) {
    try {
       integers = scanner.nextInt();
       if (integers < 1)
           throw new ArithmeticException("Must be an integer of one or     more.");
    flag = true;
    } catch (ArithmeticException eghx) {
        System.out.println(eghx.getMessage());
    }
}
positive = new int[integers];
```

but I think that using try catch is excess because you can only check input and do it while user writes correct number.